# Filter by group but showing percentage instead of number

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, filter

Is it possible to filter a list by group and showing percentage instead of numbers?

I know we can group by a list by some column but it shows no. of records. Is it possible to show percentage?

I am talking about OOB functionality where you can edit or create a new filter on any list.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOTB way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box view settings.

Grouped list views will only show the count/number of list items available for corresponding group.

---

**Additional**: "Totals" option in view settings also does not support percentage.